# Install package for python3 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

I have `ubuntu 16.04` and `python 3.5`

I'm trying to install `python-docx` package like: `pip3 install python-docx`

It says package installed successfully, though when try to import into python file like:

`import docx`, gives error: `ImportError: No module named 'docx'`

Any help appreciated

BTW, `pip3 show python-docx` shows:

```
Name: python-docx
Version: 0.8.10
Summary: Create and update Microsoft Word .docx files.
Home-page: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx
Author: Steve Canny
Author-email: python-docx@googlegroups.com
License: The MIT License (MIT)
Location: /home/otariki/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: lxml
Required-by:
```

Comment: Is this package working with python2 ?

Comment: @DevanshSoni - No, it gives same error for python2.7 project too

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check whether it was actually installed using `pip3 list`

Also please confirm whether you installed the package globally or in an environment.

you can disable env by `deactivate`

Also please try importing the module in py2

Comment: `pip3 list` shows that there is `python-docx` with version  `0.8.10`

Comment: "Also please confirm whether you installed the package globally or in an environment.", Sorry, how can I define this? I just ran command `pip3 install python-docx` for installation

Answer (score 1):

Your package is installed locally.

Something you can do is to add the `site-packages` folder to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/otariki/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

You can add that line to your `.bashrc` (or equivalent if you are not using Bash) to ensure it is set each time you open a terminal.