# Import package by location

Tags: python, python-3.5

Installed `python-docx` package for `python3.5` on `ubuntu 16.04`.

Package Installed successfully, `pip3 show python-docx` gives:

```
Name: python-docx
Version: 0.8.10
Summary: Create and update Microsoft Word .docx files.
Home-page: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx
Author: Steve Canny
Author-email: python-docx@googlegroups.com
License: The MIT License (MIT)
Location: /home/otariki/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: lxml
Required-by:
```

Then, I'm trying to import package into my python file like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/otariki/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docx')
from docx import Document
```

Gives error: `ImportError: No module named 'docx'`

What is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the `/home/otariki/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` folder. Why? The package is inside the folder `docx` (the `__init__.py` file indicates `docx` is a package).

Note: Take into account that the `$HOME/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` folder should be part of your `PYTHONPATH` by default. What I mean is: you should not need to add that folder to `sys.path`, it should be done automatically by Python.

Comment: `$HOME/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages` currently is not `PYTHONPATH` part.  I have asked related question few hours ago. Can you help me in this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405165/install-package-for-python3-on-ubuntu-16-04#61405165 ?

Comment: I'll take a look :)